# Movie with a girl summoning powers from a glowing pyramid

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is a movie I caught a glimpse of as a young child, and it has been bothering me that I have no idea what move it is.

This must have been right around 1990, and I saw it on TV, so presumably the movie was from the mid to late eighties (though it could of course be older).

I really only remember a single scene from the movie

A girl with blonde hair sat on her knees (I think), she had her palms resting on some sort of glass pyramid, which was glowing with a white/yellow light. She was screaming in some language, I got the feeling she was summoning some powers of some kind. There was a man there too, who I believe managed to stop her from whatever she was doing. If I remember correctly, he seemed to care about her, so it was not that they were enemies, but for some reason he wanted to stop her from performing the "ritual" or whatever it should be called.

Now, I only have a vague recollection of the scene, and I'm not 100% sure it was a pyramid she was holding her hands against, but it was definitely some sort of glowing pane of glass. She seemed to possess some power which the man thought was dangerous.

There is also a chance it could have been a TV show, and not a movie. It was live-action, and I assume based on the scene I remember that it was in the sci-fi or fantasy genres.

Comment: Some movies with power pyramids are *The Librarian: Quest for the Spear* and *Young Sherlock Holmes*. I don't recall them well enough to say it they fit yor description, though.

Comment: Was the light definitely white/yellow? In particular, could it have been green?

Comment: Also, can you post which country this was broadcast in? And if you remember which channel it was (eg BBC vs ITV if this was the UK.)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe "The Girl From Tomorrow", or perhaps "The Tomorrow People". See in particular the 1990s episodes listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Tomorrow_People_serials

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Thanks for the suggestions! I had a look, and unfortunately doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica sorry, I should have mentioned the country. This was in Sweden, I think it was in English though, but can't say for sure. It is possible the light could have been green, my recollection is yellowish, though it's not impossible I remember that wrong. I will take a look at your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Another possibility that just occurred to me - this could have been Ray trying to reason with Gozer near the end of Ghostbusters, although some details don't quite match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, after looking through a bit of The Girl From Tomorrow, I started thinking it was the one! But as kl78 answered, Vibes was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That sound like [Vibes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibes_(film)), a movie from 1988 with Cindy Lauper and Jeff Goldblum.

> Upon arriving, the group discovers an ancient pyramid shaped structure with mystical carvings. Sylvia translates them and they appear to reveal that the location was built by an ancient alien race who has embedded all of the psychic energy of the world into this pyramid. Using the translation Sylvia provided, Ingo attempts to decipher the secret to harnessing the energy, but before he can, Sylvia lays hands on the pyramid and allows the dangerous forces to flow through her. She kills their captors and is nearly killed herself, but survives. However, she permanently loses contact with her spirit guide Louise, who sacrifices her connection to Sylvia in order to save her and Nick in the process.

I could not find the whole film somewhere to verify but you can see the part of your description here:

Comment: That's definitely the one! Thanks! I guess I should watch Vibes now :)

Comment: Looks like they all failed the vibes check